# How to transform sub claim during authentication?

Tags: .net-core

I am using two JwtBearer authentication schemes. First one accepts JWTs where "sub" claim is raw user id and second one accepts JWTs where "sub" claim is encoded user id:

```
{"sub": "123"} // unencoded user id
{"sub": "FG#ERT$%T$#R$FRDGDFGDFG"} // encoded user id
```

After authentication I want ClaimsPrincipal to have only unencoded user id (sub) claim, so for one JwtBearer scheme I have to modify claims principal to decode user id (sub) claim. How I can do that?

---

Here is how I add authentication

```cs
builder.AddAuthentication()
   .AddJwtBearer("BearerScheme1", ...)
   .AddJwtBearer("BearerScheme2", ...)
```

So for authentication scheme "BearerScheme1" I just want to modify claim before claims principal is set on HttpContext. Right now for example when BearerScheme1 succeeds I have claim "sub" with value "xxx" and I want to modify it to be "yyy" for example. I just want to modify claims that are set by specific JwtBearerScheme.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you want to do. Also show the source code you have and explain where you get any error/problems. Please provide a [mcve] to show the problem.

Comment: I added more details, I just want to modify/transform claims during specific JwtBearer authentication.